# Checking if an array of string is sorted lexicographically case insensitive

Tags: java, arrays, string, boolean

I'm writing a method which gets as an input an array of strings and an integer `n`. the method will check if the strings up until length `n` are in lexicographical order.
My code returns false for every input and I cant figure out why!

```
public static boolean isStringArraySorted(String[] strs, int n) {
    boolean answer=true; 

    for (String word : strs) {
        for(int i=1; i<strs.length; i++) {
            String check1 =word.substring(0,n); 
            String check2= strs[i].substring(0,n);
            if ( check1.compareToIgnoreCase(check2) > 0 )
                return false; 
        }
    }

    return answer; 
}
```

Comment: You don't need two loops to solve this problem. Checking if an array is sorted is a linear time problem. Compare each string in array only with a string immediately after it.

Answer (score 1):

Change your loop to this:

```
for (int j=0; j<strs.length; j++){
    for(int i=j+1; i<strs.length; i++){
        String word = strs[j];
        String check1 =word.substring(0,n); 
        String check2= strs[i].substring(0,n);
        if (check1.compareToIgnoreCase(check2)>0)
            return false; 

    }
}
```

As the key bit you're doing wrong is that your second loop is starting in the wrong place.

Comment: There was a typo in your original answer which I fixed and noticed you have fixed it as well :)

Answer (score 1):

Because you are iterating in the inner for loop for the entire array while you should only do so from *word* onwards.

```
for (int j=1; j<strs.length; j++){
    for(int i=j+1; i<strs.length; i++){
        String word = strs[j];
        String check1 =word.substring(0,n); 
        String check2= strs[i].substring(0,n);
        if (check1.compareToIgnoreCase(check2)>0)
            return false; 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, you only need one loop to solve this problem:

```
public static boolean isStringArraySorted(String[] strs, int n) {
  for (int i = 0; i < strs.length - 1; i++) {      
    String first = substring(strs[i], n);
    String second = substring(strs[i + 1], n);
    if (first.compareToIgnoreCase(second) > 0) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

private static String substring(String s, int n) {
  return s.substring(0, n > s.length() ? s.length() - 1 : n);
}
```